# Horizotally align elements in HTML table head

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap and HTML I have created a simple calendar, which I'd like to add arrows in the head, next to the month name.
I can't align the arrows and the month:

[image: 3 divs in table head]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-bordered table-striped month">
<tr><th colspan="7" class="month-head month">
 <div>
   <div><span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
   </div>
   <div style="margin:0 auto;"> April 2017 </div>
   <div><span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
   </div>
</div></th></tr>
<tr><th class="mon text-center">Mon</th><th class="tue text-center">Tue</th><th class="wed text-center">Wed</th><th class="thu text-center">Thu</th><th class="fri text-center">Fri</th><th class="sat text-center">Sat</th><th class="sun text-center">Sun</th></tr>
...
</table>
```

Can you help me aligning the right arrow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using built in tools provided by Bootstrap.

Inside the `<th>` element, you can add the class `container-fluid` to the `<div>` tag. Then, you can apply Bootstrap's fluid grid classes such as `col-xs-3` etc. To align the sections of the calendar heading properly.

See this Bootsnipp example I made: http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/o1KRG

Comment: Also great! i didn't think I can put a `container-fluid` inside the `th`. I am glad to see it's so simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between` on the parent of those 3 elements.

```css
.top-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="top-row">
   <div><span><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>
   <div> April 2017 </div>
   <div><span><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>
</div>
```